# Apache CXF logs are not getting suppressed

Tags: java, spring, logging, cxf

We have an embedded JAX-RS web service within a stand-alone Java application using Apache CXF with Spring and having a traditional web.xml deployment descriptor to configure the beans.

When we invoke an API call from a rest client, we could see the below logs getting generated which we wanted to suppress.

```
Service http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8088-exec-9,5,main]
Create a new message for processing
Request Headers: {accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], Authorization=[***], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[2827], content-type=[application/json], host=[localhost:8088], postman-token=[e4a88b18-c864-4267-92b0-e8659007118c], Proxy-Authorization=[***], user-agent=[PostmanRuntime/7.29.2],consumer.id=[a3b799098c9e493a9b3a04ba4daedae091ajaqqo], svc.version=[2.0.0]}
Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@7ac897c2 to phase pre-stream
Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@26a32a9c was created. Current flow:
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  unmarshal [JAXRSInInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor]

Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@7ac897c2
Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor@735f6995
Trying to select a resource class, request path : /v1/api/fetch
Resource class
No method match, method name : implService, request path : /fetch, method @Path : /simulate, HTTP Method : POST, method HTTP Method : POST, ContentType : application/json, method @Consumes : application/json,application/xml,text/xml,, Accept : */*,, method @Produces : */*,.
Resource operation service may get selected
Resource operation service on the resource class 
Request path is: /v1/api/fetch
Request HTTP method is: POST
Request contentType is: application/json
Accept contentType is: */*
Found operation: fetchService
Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor@13a230be
Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor@6c4f928
```

We are looking to suppress these logs. One way I could think of is by adding below:-

```
<jaxrs:properties>
    <entry key="org.apache.cxf.Logger" value="org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger" />
</jaxrs:properties>
```

to jax rs configuration in webContext.xml:

```
<jaxrs:server address="/services">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="router${router.runas}DeliveryService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="provider" />
        <ref bean="exceptionMapper" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:properties>
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.Logger" value="org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger" />
    </jaxrs:properties>
</jaxrs:server>
```

And passing the following JVM args while starting up the application.

```
-Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.name=org.apache.cxf
-Dlog4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.level=ERROR
```

But this is not solving and we are still seeing the logs. Can someone please take a look and suggest where things are going wrong. TIA.